# I've created a GUI using wxPython and the functions aren't executed when I run my app

Tags: python, function, inheritance, button, wxpython

I'm using python 2.7 and i'm creating a GUI for a specific text editor using `wxPython`..
I've created these 2 scripts to run my program: **gui.py** and **app1.py** and i've put both of them in a single folder.

The problem is that once i run app1.py, it opens the GUI perfectly..
But when i press the buttons, the commands that i've inserted into app1.py aren't executed.. not even in the terminal like a simple print ()..

---

I'm using Python "2.7.9"

I can run **import wx**

and my **wx.__version__** is "3.0.2.0"

---

So, what's the problem with my code?

Is it a inheritance concept problem?

Should i use `super()` to fix that? If so, how am i supposed to use it?

> The **gui.py** code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- 

###########################################################################
## Python code generated with wxFormBuilder (version Jun 17 2015)
## http://www.wxformbuilder.org/
## PLEASE DO "NOT" EDIT THIS FILE!
###########################################################################  
import wx
import wx.xrc
###########################################################################
## Class MainFrame
###########################################################################

class MainFrame ( wx.Frame ):

    def __init__( self, parent ):
        wx.Frame.__init__ ( self, parent, id = wx.ID_ANY, title = u"Editor_SPED_LP", pos = wx.DefaultPosition, size = wx.Size( 320,231 ), style = wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE|wx.SYSTEM_MENU|wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL )

        self.SetSizeHintsSz( wx.Size( -1,-1 ), wx.Size( -1,-1 ) )

        bSizer1 = wx.BoxSizer( wx.VERTICAL )

        self.m_textBox = wx.TextCtrl( self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.EmptyString, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, wx.TE_LEFT|wx.TE_READONLY )
        bSizer1.Add( self.m_textBox, 0, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5 )

        self.m_btn_abrirArq = wx.Button( self, wx.ID_ANY, u"Abrir arquivo...", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
        bSizer1.Add( self.m_btn_abrirArq, 0, wx.ALL, 5 )

        self.m_btn_editarTxt = wx.Button( self, wx.ID_ANY, u"Editar .txt", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
        bSizer1.Add( self.m_btn_editarTxt, 0, wx.ALL, 5 )

        self.m_gauge1 = wx.Gauge( self, wx.ID_ANY, 100, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, wx.GA_HORIZONTAL )
        self.m_gauge1.SetValue( 0 ) 
        bSizer1.Add( self.m_gauge1, 0, wx.ALL, 5 )

        self.m_textoProgresso = wx.StaticText( self, wx.ID_ANY, u"Aguardando arquivo..", wx.Point( -1,-1 ), wx.DefaultSize, wx.ALIGN_CENTRE )
        self.m_textoProgresso.Wrap( -1 )
        bSizer1.Add( self.m_textoProgresso, 0, wx.ALL, 5 )

        self.m_btn_ajuda = wx.Button( self, wx.ID_ANY, u"Ajuda", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
        bSizer1.Add( self.m_btn_ajuda, 0, wx.ALL, 5 )


        self.SetSizer( bSizer1 )
        self.Layout()

        self.Centre( wx.BOTH )

        # Connect Events
        self.m_btn_abrirArq.Bind( wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.abrirArquivo )
        self.m_btn_editarTxt.Bind( wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.editarTxt )
        self.m_btn_ajuda.Bind( wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.janelaAjuda )

    def __del__( self ):
        pass


    # Virtual event handlers, overide them in your derived class
    def abrirArquivo( self, event ):
        event.Skip()

    def editarTxt( self, event ):
        event.Skip()

    def janelaAjuda( self, event ):
        event.Skip()
```

> The **app1.py** code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- 

#importing wx files
import wx
#import the newly created GUI file
import gui

#inherit from the MainFrame created in wxFormBuilder and create MyFrame
class MyFrame(gui.MainFrame):
    #constructor
    def __init__(self, parent):
        #initialize parent class
        gui.MainFrame.__init__(self, parent)

    #handlers for MyFrame_MainFrame events
    def abrirArquivo(self, event):
        try:
            #abrir fileDialog box
            openFileDialog = wx.FileDialog(self, "Open", "", "", "Text files (*.txt)|*.txt", wx.FD_OPEN | wx.FD_FILE_MUST_EXIST)
            openFileDialog.ShowModal()
            #salvar o caminho para o arquivo
            filepath = openFileDialog.GetPath()
            #alterar a textbox para "arquivo encontrado"

            TextCtrl.SetValue(self, "teste")
            StaticText.SetValue(self, u"Arquivo encontrado..")
        except Exception:
            print "erro_abrir_arquivo"

    def editarTxt(self, event):
        try:
            #editar texto
            dial = wx.MessageDialog(None, "TESTE", 'Ajuda - Editor SPED', wx.OK)
            dial.ShowModal()
            dial.Destroy()
        except Exception:
            print "erro_editar_txt"

    def janelaAjuda( self, event):
        try:
            #mostrar janela de ajuda
            dial = wx.MessageDialog(None, "'1 - Apertar o botao 'escolher arquivo' \n2 - Selecionar o .txt do SPED da L.P.\n3 - Aguarde o processamento..\n4 - O arquivo editado sera salvo na mesma pasta do arquivo selecionado\n5 - Fim'", 'Ajuda - Editor SPED', wx.OK)
            dial.ShowModal()
            dial.Destroy()
        except Exception:
            print "erro_jan_ajuda"

# run the app and render-it continuously
class MyApp(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        self.frame = MyFrame(None)
        self.SetTopWindow(self.frame)
        self.frame.Show(True)
        print("wxApp criado com sucesso.")
        return True
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # do not redirect stdout to the gui
    app = MyApp(redirect=False)
    # render gui continuously
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Your definition of `__del__` is raising warning signals. Why do you define `__del__` at all?

Comment: When I execute app1.py, there happens a lot when I press the buttons, I get text in the console, a file picker window, a messagebox... sure this isn't a wx installation problem?

Comment: @Oddthinking
the gui.py was created using the wxFormBuilder default python configuration...

Comment: @adrianus is there a way to check that? i've installed **wxPython3.0-win32-3.0.2.0-py27** from the www.wxpython.org

Comment: Can you run `import wx; print wx.__version__` for a first check?

Comment: @adrianus
python = "2.7.9" //
import wx = "OK" //
print wx.__version__ = "3.0.2.0"

Comment: @adrianus, i've copied both of my codes, saved them in a different folder... and when i executed it, my buttons just started to work!!
i dont know why it worked that way... do you?
anyway, it's working!! :D 
thanks for your feedbacks

Comment: Haha, nice to hear :-) Must've been some kind of a strange error... Maybe some import or filename confusion?

Comment: Did you happen to save any files named `wx.py`? That will certainly confuse it

Comment: @MikeDriscoll, i've first named them "gui.py" and "editor_sped.py". They were both inside a "desktop\proj" folder in my desktop, and in that way, "editor_sped.py" couldn't run the codes when the buttons were pressed... // Then I copied both codes that i've pasted here, saved them with "gui.py" and "editor_sped.py" filenames inside the "desktop\proj2" folder! // Curiously, running them from inside the proj2 folder they worked flawlessly!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the logbook:

As mentioned in my comment I copied both files in an empty folder and the buttons seem fully functional when I click them, I get text in the console, a file picker window, a messagebox.

To begin checking with any installation issues of `wx`, check with

```
import wx
print wx.__version__
```

if it returns a version number for your wxPython installation.

I'm glad you could solve it copying in a plain new folder, maybe some import or filename confusion happened, as it seems to work now with the two files on their own.